# What is the best value for Xft.dpi in .Xresources

Tags: x11, scaling, hidpi

From [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#X_Resources):

> For Xft.dpi, using integer multiples of 96 usually works best, e.g. 192 for 200% scaling.

I know that 200%, 300%,... scaling is the best possible because every pixel replaced with integer amount of pixels and we don't have situation where we need to display 1.5 pixels.

But what if don't have 4k monitor, and have *for example* 2.5k(2560x1440) monitor or monitor with some non-standard resolution or aspect ratio. In this case increasing scale factor 2 times is too much.

I have only 2 ideas:

- Scale it in `1.25`, `1.5`, `1.75`, so objects with `16x16` and `32x32` size will be properly scaled.
- Scale it in `(vertical_pixels*horizontal_pixels)/(1920*1080)*96`, so you will get size of objects similar to normal display.